# Regression: Finding the vector explaining most variance in 3D space

Tags: regression, pca

I have a specific regression problem of which I am not sure how to solve it.
We have a dependent variable which varies depending on a certain area that is electrically stimulated in the brain. The stimulation location is represented as 3D coordinates. A multiple regression with the three coordinates (i.e. axes) as predictors yield that two axes are significantly correlated with the DV. Hence, we should be able to find a vector that explains most of the variance and is not one of the „cardinal“ axes but somehow diagonal.

Can anybody recommend any statistical methods (maybe somehow similar to PCA) to obtain this vector? I am searching for an automatic way of finding the direction that is decisive in modulating (i.e. explains most of the variance) the DV.